# Python-Logstash sending too many entries in Pyramid application

Tags: python, pyramid

Using Logstash to record logs and also record when a user does something. Unfortunately, it seems to send multiple entries per 'action' or error instead of one per action or error. For example, if a user submits a form, I have it set to log that they've submitted. Sometimes it will record 1 log entry for that, sometimes it will record 5, or 3, or 2. It's incredibly inconsistent. Other tools and applications that log to the same server don't do this. This is where I set up logstash:

```
class LogStashExp(object):
    @staticmethod
    def log(exc, request, servfrom, erlevel, email):
        if str(request.url).startswith('http://localhost'):
            host = 'localhost'
        else:
             host = '*******'
        prlogger = logging.getLogger(str(servfrom))
        prlogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        prlogger.addHandler(logstash.LogstashHandler(host, 6123, version=1))
        extra = {
            'email': email
        }
        if erlevel == "warn":
            prlogger.warning(exc, extra=extra)
        elif erlevel == "error":
            prlogger.error(exc, extra=extra)
        elif erlevel == "info":
            prlogger.info(exc, extra=extra)
        else:
            prlogger.error(exc)
```

And I use this where I want to log something.

```
LogStashExp.log("message", request, servfrom='application', erlevel='info', email=email)
```

Ideas?

Comment: Some more info after some testing. When I build the pyramid app, the first action is logged as a single entry. The second one is logged as 2 distinct entries of the same singular action. The third, three entries. And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python `logging` has a global state.

```
    prlogger = logging.getLogger(str(servfrom))
    prlogger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    prlogger.addHandler(logstash.LogstashHandler(host, 6123, version=1))
```

First time this code is executed, it creates a logger. The second time this code is executed, it returns the same logger back. And each time the code is executed *a new logging handler is added to the existing logger*.

I think if you want to create your logger dynamically, you should check if it has any handlers before proceeding to add new ones.

Comment: Well, according to [python-logstash](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-logstash) docs, that's how it should be written. I'm not sure what you mean by "check if it has any handlers". What is "it"? My application? The only handler defined is console.

Comment: It's a tad early, maybe I shoulda waited for my coffee to kick in before commenting. I know what you mean. I'll give that a go

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember out of my head how to list handlers of a logger, but you should find out by poking `prlogger` in debug prompt

Comment: `if len(prlogger.handlers) == 0:` is the code I used. I put the addHandler code inside this `if` statement. No more duplicate records. So simple. Thanks Mikko!